# Data read from file doesn't match seemingly identical string

Tags: python, file, zip

I'm trying to read (and play) a random video from a zip file, but the string read from an index (created by `dir /b *.mp4 > data2`) doesn't match the name of the file in the archive.

```py
import os, random
from zipfile import ZipFile
#selecting a random line from a text file
line = random.choice(open('data2', "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore').readlines())
#zip file has a bunch of files in it
with ZipFile('data', 'r') as zipObject:
   list = zipObject.namelist()
   print(line)
   #it correctly prints as a string
   for fileName in list:
      # this doesn't match unless i explicitly declare
      #list = "random file from list.mp4"
      if fileName.encode == line:
         print(fileName)
         zipObject.extract(fileName, 'folder')
         os.startfile(f'folder\\{fileName}')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer in that it posts no code. Rather, I list a few tips that may be useful.

1. Is there whitespace/invisible in/around the string?
2. Could there be an issue with the encoding?

For #1, I would recommend using regex to substitute all whitespace with some visible character.

For #2, I am not sure of a solution. Perhaps try it on a system where everything is UTF-8?

Comment: 1. There is whitespace, but it's also in the file names, and I don't want to replace the names of 3200 files.
2. I forced the encoding for both to utf-8

Comment: Perhaps try things out in a more _small_ scale environment then @Alex? It may help with debugging

Comment: I tried it with 10 files name 0-9, still doesn't work.